# Would shell command join cause out of memory?

Tags: shell, memory, join

I have two file to join.

FILE 1:

```
a  A1
a  A2
a  A3
...
c  C1
c  C2
...
```

FILE 2:

```
a  feature1_of_a
a  feature2_of_a
...
a  featureN_of_a
...
...
c  feature1_of_c
c  feature2_of_c
...
```

after join, i could get File like this:

```
A1  feature1_of_a
A2  feature1_of_a
A3  feature1_of_a
A1  feature2_of_a
A2  feature2_of_a
A3  feature2_of_a
...
A1  featureN_of_a
A2  featureN_of_a
A3  featureN_of_a
...
```

In order to do that: i wrote shell command `join -11 -21 -o1.2,2.2 file1 file2`.
But the problem is: number N might be huge. So if join read all feautre of a into memory at once, memory might not be enough.

I don't know how join is implemented. WQould the momery become a problem? If so, is there any way to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

How huge do you think N might be?

Unless it is in the 'many millions' range, or you are working in an unusually tightly constrained (memory poor) environment, you are not going to run out of memory.

Comment: I tried in my 1G memory computer like this: make 10 row in file1, all of the first collum are 'a'. Then I set file2 N=2,000,000, the size of file2 is 500M, and all of the first collum of file2 are 'a' too. But then I run the commend "join -11 -21 -o1.2,2.2 file1 file2", it crashed. Do you know why it happened?

Comment: It ran out of memory because you're not being very sensible in your request.  You're doing a Cartesian product of the rows in file1 and the rows in file2.  I'm a little surprised it was unable to hold all of 500 MB in main memory.  I don't know if it makes any difference if you reorder file1 and file2 on the command line (worth a try because it is easy), but I won't be surprised to find it makes no difference.  Are you on a 32-bit machine or 64-bit?  More saliently, is the `join` executable 32-bit or 64-bit?  Are you sure the output is useful?